# Possible to display public images using instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How i can load public images  using instagram without the use access tokens and client id.what all things are required to show public photos of instagram.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be retrieving media information from Instagram's API, you will at the very least need an access token. Here is the endpoint for retrieving public, popular media https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_popular:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```